# Collection of coordinates in table field (database)

Tags: php, javascript, sql, database, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "wijken": {
        "11": {
            "coords": "3.79073170001967,51.1717753664505,0 3.79020920176376,51.1723018883706,0 3.78989543642226,51.1729670713336,0 3.78983091856725,51.1736482209016,0 3.79035112720225,51.174896701853,0 3.79089521566258,51.1755715564749,0 3.7915999971046,51.1759188204827,0 3.79248490395883,51.1767623261609,0 3.79147318323356,51.1776832394604,0 ",
            "id": "kml_1",
            "fid": "0",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "11",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Kanaaldorpen en -zone",
            "wijknr": "11",
            "objectid": "1",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        }
...
```

Now I want to load this data in my database. This works for "id" and "wijk". But how can I load "coords" into my table field?

And what are the properties of the field? (decimal, int, ... ?)

Comment: This works for "id" and "wijk" - What works?

Comment: what coords really represent? if its contain more values then you can store it in another table like simple floats and use FK like `wijken_id` otherwise you can use simple text column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lood coords as a single text field, or you may create a separate table for it.

Comment: If there's always the same number of coords, you could create columns coord1, coord2, ... in your table, otherwise I'd create a new table with wijken_id and coord columns.

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? Some engines (like MS SQL Server) have their own type for that: `GEOGRAPHY`

If you are using MySQL or postgreSQL the usual way is creating a new table for that, as you can see in the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createtable):

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the database normalization principles (more accurate the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) you should have anatomical structure of your fields, i.e. each column should be responsible for the representation of a single value.

Depending on your domain each coordinate can be inside different column or even table...

For example if you have a domain object City then the table City might look something like:

```
________________________________________________
|---|----------|-----------|------|------------|
|id | latitude | longitude | name | population |
|___|__________|___________|______|____________|
```

- Note the following principles are applies for relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

What is you DBMS?

If you use a Relational DBMS like MySQL, save the data in a text field and you PHP `implode` and `explode` function to manipulate this data. You can also save it in another separated table and call the `JOIN` expression in SQL query (with the help of `GROUP BY` and `group_concat()`) to get the data.

If you use a document-based DBMS like MongoDB, feel free to save the `coords` field as a array of float.